# Incorrect result when you execute a query that uses WITH RECOMPILE option in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just read the Brent Ozar Weekly Links email (July 28th Edition), and noticed the "Kendra's Link" talking about "Fix: Incorrect result when you execute a query that uses WITH RECOMPILE option in SQL Server 2012"

I replied to Brent Ozar's email, and Brent suggested that I post my question here instead of asking him to reply to me privately.

I had just finished patching all of our SQL Server 2012 servers in July to apply SQL Server 2012 SP2 plus the hotfix for the "data loss during online index rebuilds", so my servers are now at version 11.00.5522.0.

I did a little bit of research on this new hotfix.  I came to the conclusion that there is not a way to patch our systems with this new fix yet.

Here is the email I just sent to my manager. Do you guys agree with what I've pasted below:

Now that we’ve upgraded to SQL Server 2012 SP2 already, we don’t have a way to apply this new hotfix fix as of right now.

The fix was released in SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU11 (version 11.00.3449.0). As of this month, we are now at SQL Server 2012 SP2 plus the hotfix for the data loss during online index rebuild problem (version 11.00.5522.0).

You’d think that since we are at a version higher than the fix, we’d be covered. You know how they say that all the service packs include the previous service pack plus all the cumulative updates for the previous service packs, and all versions include everything from the versions below that version. Well, that’s not entirely true. Microsoft continues releasing CU’s for the previous service pack even after the new service pack is locked in QA. So they then have to play “catch-up” with the new service pack.

In reality, this is how it worked this time for the transition from SP1 to SP2:

• SQL Server 2012 SP2 (what I just patched all our SQL Server 2012 servers to) – includes SP1 plus CU1-CU9. It does not include SP1 CU10 or SP1 CU11.

• SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU1 was just released (last week I think) – that includes SP1 plus CU1-CU10. It does not include SP1 CU11 .

• That’s as far as MS has gotten with SP2. They haven’t released a CU for SP2 that includes the fixes from SP1 CU11 yet.

I assume there will be an SP2 CU2 coming out soon that will contain this fix, and we’ll probably want to talk about doing another round of SQL patching when that does get released.

Comment: What are you asking?  If the email you sent is worded correctly?

Comment: Sorry.   I was asking if my understanding of the situation is correct.  that even if I have SP2 applied, I don't have all the fixes from SP1 CU11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your question is, "Is the hotfix in https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2965069 included in Service Pack 2?" The answer as of July 28, 2014 is no. Watch that KB article to see when it changes - I use http://www.WatchThatPage.com for stuff like this.